# HTTP Get Request does not call Wix Code Method

Tags: javascript, velo

I am working on a WIX website that posts these "events" that people can sign up for. I am trying to make sure that these events are hidden from the front end when the event is over. I have created a "show" boolean that the repeater checks if the show value is true. What I am trying to do is make the "show" value false if the event is over.

I have gotten this to work by calling a method every time someone visits the page that queries the database for any items that are older than today's date and sets those items "show" value to false. The issue is that the page takes a while to load when that happens. While I would like to do is use a cron service to call a method a couple of times a day. The only way I could see to do this is to use the wix-http functions to call the method. Here is my code so far:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import {ok} from 'wix-http-functions';

export function use_eventExpire() {
    var today = new Date();     //Gets todays date
    return wixData.query("Events")  //Begins Query of "Events" Database
        .le("endTime", today)   //Looks for items that are older than 
//today's date
        .eq("show", true)       //Looks for items that have the "show" 
//value as true
        .find()                 //Ends query
        .then((results) => {    //Gets Results
            let numberOfItems = results.length;     //Gets Number 
//of Items from Query
            var i = 0;                              //Declares iterator
            for (; i < numberOfItems; i++) {  //Loops through all items
                let items = results.items[i]; //Loops through all items
                items.show = false; //Sets items "show" value to false
                wixData.update("Events", items)     //Updates Database
                    .then((results) => {            //If successful
                        console.log("Successfull: " + results);     //Logs Results
                    }).catch((err) => {             //If unsuccessful
                        console.log("There was an Error: " + err);  
//Logs Error
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

When I go to the link, it returns ok, but nothing is called and the database is not updated. What do I need to change?

Comment: You should debug your code or add more log statements in order to be sure the relevant code is called (is results.length > 0?).

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your use of promises and the return statement.  You should include bluebird (for example) to help you iterate over the array.  http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

```
// make sure you include bluebird - not sure if you are working client side or server side

function updateEvent(item) {
    item.show = false;
    return wixData.update("Events", items);
}

export function use_eventExpire() {
    var today = new Date(); //Gets todays date
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        return wixData.query("Events") //Begins Query of "Events" Database
            .le("endTime", today) //Looks for items that are older than today's date
            .eq("show", true) //Looks for items that have the "show" value as true
            .find(); //Ends query
    }).then((results) => { //Gets Results
        return Promise.map(results, updateEvent);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }).finally(() => {
        console.log("all finished");
    });
}
```

Comment: I added an ok return for the .finally(), and the webpage worked, but the database did not update like I was expecting. Was there something more I was missing?